# Compare field values from different users

Tags: sql, sapb1

Ok so this has been doing my head in for a while and the code has gone through a few different iterations.

I need to know if a technician has changed a time on service call and report a TRUE or FALSE statement.

Using the below example, the user of ID 60 IS NOT a technician and user 29 IS a technician.

We can see in log instance 10 that the technician (user 29) changed the time from the preexisting value that user id 60 had set (log instance 7) so this would report as TRUE. Otherwise, if there are no instances of changes by a technician I would instead need to return a false value.

Any other entries are irrelevant here, I just need to compare the start and end times from a technician with the last start and end time entries from a non-technician before hand (nothing afterwards).

If there are no entries by a technician it should still report a FALSE value.

A technician can be identified by the `roleID` of -2 on the HEM6 table which i have included. This query will become a subquery of a main query joined by the `callID`.

Apologies if this request is a bit wordy, happy to clarify if I can.

```
SELECT 
    T1.StartTime AS [Current start time],
    T1.endTime AS 'Current End Time',
    T2.LogInstanc,
    T2.usersign2
FROM
    ASC6 T1 
INNER JOIN 
    ASCL T2 ON T2.LogInstanc = T1.[logInstanc] 
            AND T2.callID = T1.SrcvCallID
INNER JOIN 
    OUSR T3 ON T3.INTERNAL_K = T2.usersign2
INNER JOIN 
    OHEM T4 ON T4.userid = T3.userid
LEFT JOIN 
    HEM6 T5 ON T5.empID = T4.empID
WHERE 
    T1.srcvcallID = 25557
```

Results from this query:

| Start Time | End Time | Log Instance | Updating User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8:54 | 9:09 | 2 | 1 |
| 15:30 | 16:00 | 3 | 60 |
| 15:30 | 16:00 | 4 | 60 |
| 15:30 | 16:30 | 5 | 60 |
| 15:30 | 17:00 | 6 | 60 |
| 15:30 | 16:30 | 7 | 60 |
| 15:30 | 16:30 | 8 | 29 |
| 15:30 | 16:30 | 9 | 29 |
| 15:45 | 16:45 | 10 | 29 |
| 15:45 | 16:45 | 11 | 29 |
| 15:45 | 16:45 | 12 | 60 |

[image]

Comment: Please show BOTH sample input data and the expected result as tables with text, never use images or links because no one can copy the text from an image to try out a possible solution. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors. If you are able to do that, creating a fiddle to allow people to replicate this would be best.

Comment: collect all the necessary data in one table. from this table show an example of how it should be. From what you presented it is not clear what you want to get in the end.

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler I have updated the post to include the result set as a table.

No luck yet Praxiom

Comment: How in your results set can you tell if the user is a technician? From there, a simple case statement would probably get you what you need.

Comment: Hi @ClearlyClueless, i mentioned in my post that a technician is identified by the roleID of -2 in the HEM6 table which is joined.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i think i got this figured out, all the tests so far have implied it works.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT 
A.startTime AS [StartTime],
A.endTime AS [EndTime],
B.LogInstanc,
B.usersign2,
LAG(A.startTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY B.Loginstanc ASC) AS 'ChangedStartTime',
LAG(A.endTime,1) OVER(ORDER BY B.Loginstanc ASC) AS 'ChangedEndTime'
FROM ASC6 A 
INNER  JOIN ASCL B ON B.LogInstanc = A.[logInstanc] AND B.callID = A.SrcvCallID
INNER JOIN OUSR C ON C.INTERNAL_K = B.usersign2
INNER JOIN OHEM D ON D.userid = C.userid
LEFT JOIN HEM6 E ON E.empID = D.empID
WHERE A.srcvcallID = T0.callID AND
A.Technician <> 104 AND
 A.Technician IS NOT NULL
)P
WHERE (P.StartTime <> P.ChangedStartTime OR P.endTime <> P.ChangedEndTime) AND
P.usersign2 IN (SELECT S.internal_k FROM OUSR S INNER JOIN OHEM X ON x.userid = s.userid INNER JOIN HEM6 T ON T.empID = X.empID WHERE T.roleID = -2)
GROUP BY P.loginstanc 
ORDER BY P.loginstanc DESC
```

By using the LAG function i've offset the time to indicate where a change occured, as I only need to know if the technician changed the time i've excluded everyone else.
If the technician did change the time then it will display a 1 in the count, otherwise there is no results.